# Multiple rewrite rules and conditions in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

In my .htaccess file i have already some rewrite conditions and rules, and its working normal.

Now i need to add "http to https redirect" to my htaccess file.

Here is my old .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)$   pages/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$   pages/$1/$2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$   pages/$1/$2/$3.php [L]
```

I attempted to add below code to file but it doesnt work properly.
For example if i write the url direct to browser its work (only with www). But if click my any backlinks or google search result links it doesnt work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Where do i wrong? Where should i put the code? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Please define **it doesnt work properly**

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Do you get a 404 or ssl error?

Comment: I get too many redirect error.

Answer (score 2):

your htaccess could look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yoursite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)$ pages/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$   pages/$1/$2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$   pages/$1/$2/$3.php [L]
```

At least, it works for me, in my own implementation

Comment: i got "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error from chrome. it doesnt work.

Comment: Thank you i am already using this tool. It gives me no error but it doesnt work on server.

Comment: @feyyaz did you ever resolve this? (I know it was logged a while ago but I'm getting this now!)

Comment: maybe it gives redirect errors when your site has not the www prefix. you should then remove it from the HTTP_POST

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Clear your browser's cache before testing this

Comment: Url changed to https but its throw an "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error in chrome. Page not opening.

Comment: When i look at developer tools network section, i see 21 301 redirect to same url. Thats why i got too many redirect error.

Comment: do you have any other rules?

Comment: actually i have but i turn them to comment line. now i just using your code above. i am just tyring to open my home page url it doesnt work.

Comment: This code works on my server.  I want to see your full htaccess, please post it

Comment: I deleted everything in my htacces file and just paste your code. But still not work.

Comment: I'm the same - I get too many redirects (error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS) when using this